# Oracle Forms 10g/11g : web or desktop-based?

Tags: oracleforms

I've only used Oracle Forms 6i. Is Oracle Forms 10g and 11g web-based only? Or does it still have a runtime environment for the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with Oracle Forms 9i, it is only web based.

Source: [Forms Upgrade Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/forms-upgrade-reference-128184.pdf)